# Composition of Permutations, and Expressing a Product of Disjoint Cycles as a Product of Transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm struggling with the idea of expressing permutations as a product of transpositions. For example, a question I've been given is: Let $\alpha, \beta$ be permutations in $S_8$ where

$\alpha=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\2&3&1&4&7&6&5&8\end{bmatrix}$

$\beta=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\4&5&6&7&8&1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$

Find $\alpha\circ\beta$ and $\beta\circ\alpha$.

For $\alpha\circ\beta$ I'm getting $(1458)(2736)$, but the solution provided is $(14)(27)(36)(58)$. Similarly, for the second part I got $(1526)(3478)$, but the solution provided is $(15)(26)(34)(78)$.

I guess my question is: Are my solutions correct? If so, how can they be expressed in the form of a product of transpositions like the solutions provided? If my solutions are incorrect, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your solutions appear correct, and are definitely different from the provided ones.

Comment: You cannot in general express a permutation as a product of disjoint transpositions, but only as a product of disjoint cycles, as you just did. The length of these cycles is an invariant, so your solution and the ones provided cannot be the same (one has lengths 4-4 and the other 2-2-2-2, so they cannot be equal). That being said, the provided solutions look wrong to me

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right.

One can see this by checking what the individual elements map to: for example,

$$4\stackrel{\beta}{\mapsto} 7\stackrel{\alpha}{\mapsto} 5,$$ so $(\alpha\circ\beta)4=5$, which agrees with your answer, not the supposed solution.